# Jscript String.split on csv file, Ignores leading empty fields

Tags: csv, split, jscript

Hey guys I need some help figuring out how to write this jscript so it includes the empty fields separated by commas at the beginning and puts them in an array.

```
temp = new Array;
String = ",,field3,field4,,field6";
temp = String.split(regexp, -1);
```

I have a regexp that will pick out the commas. But I know split ignores empty fields. I need those fields since I am working with reading a csv file. So I need the array to contain empty strings where there is an empty data field.

What I want

> temp[0] = "",
>   temp[1] = "", 
>   temp[3] = field 3

What it is

> temp[0] = field3

Like that, any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for JScript's rather peculiar behavior* is to use a string (not a regexp) separator:

```
var s = ",,field3,field4,,field6";
var a = s.split(",");
WScript.Echo("a:", a.length, "[" + a.join(",") + "]");
var b = s.split(/,{1,1}/);
WScript.Echo("b:", b.length, "[" + b.join(",") + "]");
```

output:

```
cscript 30603770.js
a: 6 [,,field3,field4,,field6]
b: 3 [field3,field4,field6]
```

(*) At least one other Javascript implementation behaves as it should:

```
Rhino 1.7 release 5 PRERELEASE 2013 07 16
js> var s = ",,field3,field4,,field6";
js> var a = s.split(",");
js> print("a:", a.length, "[" + a.join(",") + "]");
a: 6 [,,field3,field4,,field6]
js> var b = s.split(/,/);
js> print("b:", b.length, "[" + b.join(",") + "]");
b: 6 [,,field3,field4,,field6]
```